# How To Determine Connected Wifi WLAN Interface in Windows with C/C++?

Tags: c++, windows, wifi

***On Windows, how can I determine which Wifi WLAN interface returned by `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()` is connected?***

I am successfully using `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()` on Windows 8 to scan for a list of Wifi WLAN access points and determine their SSID, BSSID, signal strength, and other information. I am following the example on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN reference page.

Yet, for all the interfaces `WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO` I receive, I cannot determine how to tell which access point, if any, is currently connected (i.e. `wlan_interface_state_connected`).

On the Mac, I use `scanForNetworksWithSSID` from the `CoreWLAN` foundation, and the result has a *connected* `bssid` field which I can compare with each `bssid` from the scan results to determine which one of them is connected. I am looking for a similar Windows solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**:

The answer is to use `WlanQueryInterface()` (operationally similar to and used in parallel with `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()`) to determine the [WLAN_CONNECTION_ATTRIBUTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WLAN_ASSOCIATION_ATTRIBUTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the connected adapter. There is an example demonstrating the use of `WlanQueryInterface()` in the MSDN documentation at the bottom of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.

I solved the problem by calling `WlanQueryInterface()` to determine the `connectedSSID` of the connected Wifi WLAN Adapter, if there is one. Then, I compare it with the `SSID` values for each of the Adapters referenced in `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()`. A match, if there is one, determines the scanned adapter that is connected.

Note: I could also have compared BSSID values for a similar and possibly more reliable result.